# Heteromaternal Superfecundation - Any known cases?

Tags: reproduction, mammals, reproductive-biology

Superfecundation in mammals (fertilization of two or more ova from the same cycle by sperm from separate acts of sexual intercourse) -- Is possible in nature from different fathers (Heteropaternal) as after the first zygote is formed, a second act of intercourse within a certain time span has the potential (of another ovum is present) to form a second zygote.

Has there been any cases where a naturally pregnant mammal was implanted (IVF) with a second zygote from a different set of parents?  Heteromaternal/paternal Superfecundation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be termed [superfetation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfetation) rather than superfecundation. While this extremely rarely happens in humans, superfetation does occur naturally in some mammalian species. These pregnancies occur when the mother ovulates after she is pregnant.

Superfetation consisting of a natural pregnancy and implanted embryo has been done in cattle. In this case, 7-day embryos were successfully transferred to 14-day pregnant cows to produce superfetation. See Joel Carter's dissertation [Superfetation in Beef Cattle](http://etd.lsu.edu/docs/available/etd-0730102-222405/unrestricted/Carter_dis.pdf) (2002).

There have also been successful cases of superfetation in cows that were first implanted with a 7-day embryo, and then followed by natural service. See WH Hall, [Bovine superfetation by natural conception secondary to an embryo transfer pregnancy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3677712), *Cornell Vet.* 1987 Jul;77(3):282-3.

An excellent summary of the existing literature on superfetation in many species is K Roellig et al., [The concept of superfetation: a critical review on a ‘myth’ in mammalian reproduction](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20394608), *Biol Rev Camb Philos Soc.* 2011 Feb;86(1):77-95.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking about. If I'm understanding the OP correctly, by "heteromaternal superfecundation" they mean that the implanted zygote's genomic mother is not the same individual as the mother in whose womb the zygote has been implanted. This is emphasized by the later clarification "different set of parents".